# Iframe and Cookies

Tags: jquery, iframe, cookies

I'am interested how it's possible to write a cookie for iframe?

For example i have 3 iframes on my website, when user check 1 of them i need to save(write) this in cookie, and when client will be back, same iframe (which he/she choose and we write in cookie) site should display?

Thanks

---

Thanks for your comments guys, but problem isn't solved, please see my last comment where i explain what i really want to do..

"with no success :( it's not working, i can show you the workin example, and you will understand what i am doing :) see.. tvrain.ru bottom of the flowplayer if you click Настройки качества - it will be open qualities, when you chose one of them it's writing in cookie, and in next time for me it would be same quality...so this is my task :S please help!

Comment: "check one of them" you mean focus? a code sample could be helpful

Answer (score 0):

check out https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/

Writing and reading the cookie is easy, see the examples..

I'm not sure what your asking about the iframes?

EDIT

Set cookie on player page

```
$.cookie('quality_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
```

Then on main page read the cookie

```
$.cookie('quality_cookie');
```

and set the default accordingly .. more jquery :)

Comment: htt://www.onews.ge bottom of player is quality switcher, 3 different switcher, for flowplayer... when user check one of them i want to save this setting for this user and after when user will be back on website  last choose would be appear

Comment: i see, so its same domain which is good.
On the player http://onews.ge/player/ page set the cookie and then read it on main page

Comment: with no success :(  it's not working, i can show you the workin example, and you will understand what i am doing :) see..
http://tvrain.ru bottom of the flowplayer if you click Настройки качества - it will be open qualities, when you chose one of them it's writing in cookie, and in next time for me it would be same quality...so this is my task :S please help @Vince Lowe

Answer (score 0):

What server are you using? IIS or Apache?

There's a cross-domain cookie trick in IIS that requires you to set a trusted header on the server:

http://programmingschools.blogspot.com.au/2007/05/create-cookies-cross-domain.html

I personally don't recommend using this, I have worked on a site for 4 years that uses this method to set 7 cross-domain cookies and it's a freaking nightmare to manage.

Alternatively if you had something like this:

www.myparenturl.com

with this displayed in an iframe:

www.myiframeurl.com

you could set up an ajax call (or even just a straight forward a tag) in the iframe that polls the parent url and tells it which domain to set the cookie to e.g.

www.myparenturl.com/set-cookie?domain=iframe1

This would negate the need to set cross-domain cookies.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question :) see my comment up